# react - input change not firing when select all to delete

Tags: reactjs

The text section below the textbox will show the same value as textbox and change when the value of textbox changes.
But if I refresh the page and then select all(command + a) in the textbox and click delete,
The textbox become empty, 
But the text in the text section do not change accordingly.

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-williams-fu9ps?file=/src/App.js:321-378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` instead of `defaultValue` for input tag

```
<input
            id="taskRef"
            type="text"
            value={defaultData ? defaultData.message.taskRef : null}
            onChange={onInputChange}
/>
```